# WPF .NET Core Installer on VS 2019

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, windows-installer, .net-core-3.0

I am looking to create an installer for a WPF application with .NET Core 3.0 (not a console application) in Visual Studio 2019.

Can you help me out with some suggestions for any third-party tools or any other way it can be done?

I have already looked into ClickOnce and Wix, but both don't provide any option to create an installer for the above.

I know there are 2 ways to publish a .NET Core application, but I need to create an installer after that and I cannot find anything that will help me achieve the objective.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised to find that Wix starts to support this *after .NET Core 3.0 is actually released*. When working with preview bits, there are often things missing :(

Comment: There appears to be work in progress on the tooling side, but there isn't a good way yet. E.g. there are PRs on tooling repositories to allow for installer projects to reference .NET Core projects and get all the necessary output (new MSBuild output groups to be specific).

Comment: `dotnet publish` gives you the actual binaries, and then any installer technologies (even copy-and-paste) can let you install them on another machine and run. So your question itself is not really valid. Besides, such questions are off-topic. Like others commented, there might be extra support for .NET Core 3.0 to simplify certain things, but nothing prevents you from doing an installer today with WiX. ClickOnce is a dying thing, so I won't assume it a feasible option for any application.

Comment: You cannot create a WPF .NET CORE 3.0 application below VS 2019(except console apps) and WIX extension is only avaliable till VS 2017. Yes I could copy paste but it has lot of shortcomings. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The [WiX Toolset](http://wixtoolset.org/) could definitely be used to pack up a published .NET Core 3.0 application. It will take a bit of elbow grease as there isn't deep tool integration (as Jon Skeet correctly suggests)... yet.

Steps would be something like:

1. Publish .NET Core project
2. Reference all the files in published folder in 1 or more .wxs files
3. Build .wixproj of .wxs files *after* publish .NET Core project

I'm pretty confident this will work even though I've not used.NET Core 3.0 yet because we've done something very similar for a complex .NET Core 2.0 application at [FireGiant](https://www.firegiant.com/).

Comment: in #2 above, are you saying that every single file (inc. every single .js in a .net core web app) would need individual referencing?

Comment: Yes. You need to specify which files get included in the setup project. You can specify them by hand individually or use [some sort of harvesting](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/wep-documentation/harvesting/).

Answer (score 0):

For deploying a .NET Core application internally in your organization, you can create an msix package. I'm successfully using it as a Clickonce replacement.

You can check [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61924553/12798097) explaining how to create an msix package for a .NET Core project. You can even target Windows 7 SP1 and later.